# -PipelineVariable not working on Get-NetIPAddress

Tags: powershell

I'm obviously failing to understand the nuances to `-PipelineVariable`

If I pass `Get-NetIPAddress` into `Get-NetAdapter` it shows the associated adapters.

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now if I want to also collect the IP I decided I'd just tack it on

```
Get-NetIPAddress -PipelineVariable ip | Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object *,@{n='IP';e={$ip.IPAddress}}
```

However I see the error

```
Get-NetIPAddress : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:5
+     Get-NetIPAddress -PipelineVariable ip
```

Even just simply running this gets the same error

```
Get-NetIPAddress -PipelineVariable ip | Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This also returns the same error.

```
Get-NetIPAddress -PipelineVariable ip | Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name      = $_.Name
                IfDesc    = $_.Interfacedescription
                IfIndex   = $_.ifindex
                MAC       = $_.macaddress
                LinkSpeed = $_.linkspeed
                IP        = $ip.IPAddress
            }
        }
```

Is this not how it was intended to be used? Originally I was using Where-Object to filter against IPv4 address family, but omitted it for this example.

Working around it like this just seems wrong.

```
foreach($ip in Get-NetIPAddress){
    $ip | Get-NetAdapter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name      = $_.Name
            IfDesc    = $_.Interfacedescription
            IfIndex   = $_.ifindex
            MAC       = $_.macaddress
            LinkSpeed = $_.linkspeed
            IP        = $ip.IPAddress
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala same error, it seems the select object is insignificant. Even just by itself `Get-NetIPAddress -pipelinevariable blah` gives the error. Many, many, many other cmdlets work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're seeing **a bug in *Windows PowerShell* that affects *all* so-called [CDXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/cdxml-overview) cmdlets**, of which `Get-NetIPAddress` is one instance.

- CDXML cmdlets are implemented declaratively via `*.cdxml` XML documents that define a "mapping between PowerShell cmdlets and CIM class operations or methods."

**Seemingly, in Windows PowerShell *no* CDXML cmdlets support the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable)** and report the `Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet` error you saw:

```bash
# !! Fails in Windows PowerShell.
# OK in PowerShell (Core) v7.2+
PS> Get-NetIPAddress -PipelineVariable var | 
      Select IPAddress, @{ Name='IPAddressViaPipelineVar'; Expression = { $var.IPAddress } }

Get-NetIPAddress : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Note:

- The bug is present as of Windows PowerShell version v5.1.19041.1151.
- Windows PowerShell, whose latest and *final* version is v5.1, is not being actively developed anymore, and [will see *high-priority* bug fixes only](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/#future-of-windows-powershell).
- It is therefore unlikely that this bug will be fixed, but it can't hurt to report it [via the Feedback Hub application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).

---

In ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***:

- The **bug has been fixed in v7.2+**.

  - However, **there is a *related* bug**, still present as of v7.3.8: If you use `-PipelineVariable` with a CDXML cmdlet and *another* CDXML cmdlet is used in the same pipeline (without `-PipelineVariable`), the latter unexpectedly resets the pipeline variable to `$null` - see [GitHub issue #20546](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20546).

**Caveat**: I'm unclear on the official maintenance status of CDXML cmdlets:

- The linked CDXML documentation is marked as *no longer being updated*.
- In the still-maintained documentation, CDXML cmdlets are only mentioned in passing, in the conceptual [about_CimSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CimSession) help topic.
- PowerShell (Core) uses the very same CDXML modules that Windows PowerShell does: they come with Windows PowerShell (in subfolders of `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`). However, there is an edition-specific, dynamic transformation step involved, namely the transformation of the `*.cdxml` XML files into PowerShell functions, which then use edition-specific types such as `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]`.

The following command lists **all locally available modules that contain CDXML cmdlets**:

- Note: This **takes quite a while** and explicitly *imports all locally available into the current session*, so that all function bodies can be examined.
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* - but not in Windows PowerShell - the following problems occur:

  - *Errors* are reported (`Add-Type: Assembly with same name is already loaded.`, `Operation is not supported on this platform (0x80131539)`), which are suppressed with `-ErrorAction Ignore`
  - Implicit remoting modules are created, presumably via the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility).
  - Most of the modules do *not* report the set of exported functions, and show a version number of `0.0`.

```bash
Get-Command -Type Function | 
  % { if (-not $_.Module) { return } Import-Module -WarningAction Ignore -EA Ignore $_.Module; if ((Get-Content -EA Ignore "function:$($_.Name)") -match 'cdxml') { $_.Module } } | 
    Sort-Object Name, @{ Expression={ $_.Version }; Descending=$true } -Unique
```

Comment: Dang that stinks. I appreciate the additional details.

Comment: @DougMaurer, yes, it's unfortunate; my guess is that the reason this is neither widely known nor has been fixed is the relative obscurity of the `-PipelineVariable` parameter. I've added some more details to the answer, including the currently recommended way to report WinPS bugs (it changed recently) - but I wouldn't hold my breath that this will get fixed.

Comment: I appreciate the additional details too, but I hope you haven't been holding your breath, because this still doesn't seem to be fixed ... (PowerShell 7.3.8) 

Comment: @Alexis-EmmanuelHaeringer: I'm not surprised that it won't get fixed in _Windows PowerShell_, but it does seem to (still) work for me in _PowerShell (Core)_ v7.3.8 and v7.4.0-preview.6.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! maybe this following isn't a possible command (even with $using.var.InterfaceDescription)?
`(Get-NetAdapter -PipelineVariable var).where{$_.Status -eq 'Up'}  |  Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |select IPAddress,InterfaceAlias,@{Name='Desc';E={$var.InterfaceDescription}}`

Comment: @Alexis-EmmanuelHaeringer: There's a conceptual flaw in your command: Using `(...)` creates a _nested_ pipeline, and a pipeline variable created inside of that isn't visible to the enclosing pipeline. However, you did hit _another_ bug: See [GitHub issue #20546](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20546). To work around it, use `Get-NetAdapter | Write-Output -PipelineVariable var | Where-Object Status -eq Up | ...`